# Specific stdout line order with multi-processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have the following problem:

`g` data generators, each in it's separate `Process`, produces `n` value that I need to write out in a round-robin (over `g`) fashion. So for generators `A`, `B`, `C`, the output must be in-order like:

```
<value 1 of A>
<value 1 of B>
<value 1 of C>
<value 2 of A>
<value 2 of B>
<value 2 of C>
<value 3 of A>
...
```

Functionally it is working, but still much slower than single-threaded. As I need to generate large number of values I wanted to parallelize the generation (and possibly also the output, which is what I wasn't able to so far).

Code (*updated to use `mp.Pipe` and include separate data generators*):

```py
import random
import argparse
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys


class DataGenerator:
    _id = 0

    def __init__(self, id: int, **kwargs):
        self._id = id

    def generate(self):
        return '%03d:%4x' % (self._id, random.getrandbits(16))


def produce(generator, pipe, num: int):
    p_read, p_write = pipe
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        i += 1
        p_write.send(generator.generate())


def consume(pipes: list, num: int):
    i = 0
    p_count = len(pipes)

    while i < num:
        # enforce round-robin printing...
        p_idx = i % p_count
        p_read, p_write = pipes[p_idx]

        i += 1
        sys.stdout.write(p_read.recv() + '\n')


def multi_processed(num: int, processes: int):
    per_process = int(num / processes)
    if num % processes != 0:
        per_process += 1

    q = list()
    g = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        q.append(mp.Pipe(False))
        g.append(DataGenerator(i + 1))

    procs = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=produce, args=(g[i], q[i], per_process))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    consume(q, num)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()


def single_threaded(num: int, processes: int):
    g = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        g.append(DataGenerator(i + 1))

    for i in range(num):
        j = i % processes
        print(g[j].generate())


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Threading test')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--count', '-c', dest='count', type=int, default=1000000,
        help='How many total iterations (default: 1000000)')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--threads', '-t', dest='threads', type=int, default=1,
        help='how many threads to use (default: 1 - single-threaded)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.threads > 1:
        multi_processed(args.count, abs(args.threads))
    else:
        single_threaded(args.count, mp.cpu_count())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While executing, it is hogging on all my 4 CPU cores but performance-wise it's slower than sequential execution:

Execution times for 10,000,000 total values single-threaded:

```
$ time python3 threading_output.py --threads 1 --count 10000000 | wc -l
10000000

real    0m16.557s
user    0m16.443s
sys     0m0.437s
```

...and the same for the `multiprocessing` implementation:

```
$ time python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000 | wc -l
10000000

real    1m6.446s
user    3m10.073s
sys     0m54.274s
```

Without using the `mp.Queue` and directly printing the generated values inside the `produce` loop gives me ~9.6 seconds, but of course, no deterministic order of the output lines.

*How can I speed this up?*

#### Update #1

Using `mp.Array` is not an option for a shared buffer because I'd need to use ctype `c_wchar_p` for an array of strings, which is not going to work out at all according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes).

#### Update #2

Replaced the `mp.Queue(1000)` with `mp.Pipe(False)`, which brought the time down to ~45 seconds for 10 million values. The producer processes are now much less hogging on the CPU and the consumer is the clear bottleneck:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5943 ancoron   20   0   28420  15168   8348 R  99.9   0.0   0:12.23 `- python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000
 5947 ancoron   20   0   28284  10336   3536 R  29.9   0.0   0:03.69     `- python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000
 5948 ancoron   20   0   28284  10336   3536 R  30.8   0.0   0:03.71     `- python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000
 5949 ancoron   20   0   28284  10336   3536 R  30.8   0.0   0:03.71     `- python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000
 5950 ancoron   20   0   28284  10340   3536 R  29.0   0.0   0:03.58     `- python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000
```

#### Update #3

I tried with [cinda](https://cinda.readthedocs.io/), using a simple `BytesQueue`, which brought it down to ~23 seconds. Still slower than single-threaded.

Comment: ??? They don't need to and that wouldn't make any difference, since the producers are only running as long they `put` values to the `Queue` and the `consume` basically serves as data-wise `join`. But please explain, why would a missing `join` result into non-idle CPU cycles in this implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure it would be faster, but perhaps [pebble](https://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/) might be helpful? I've got some experience with it, and I think in your case the pebble.map function (which returns an iterator of the results in the order you gave it to the map) might be exactly what you're looking for. I can say with some certainty that it would speed it up and wouldn't take long to do. Adjusting your current implementation is out of my league and wish you the best of luck. I can help you with Pebble, though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Ancoron, actually on i7 Intel proc I see no issues with copy-pasted code above. Is there any other additional context in your actual code?

Comment: @Anocoron I'm sorry, but can you verify my thoughs? If I understood you right than you want an output like that, right?
"A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2", "A3", "B3", "C3", (and so on)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: this is my actual test code, I know that it works, my problem is performance only

Comment: @TornaxO7: yes, exactly. Where `A`, `B` and `C` are generators/processes and `1`, `2`, `...` represents the first, second, ... generated value of the respective generator/process. As you can see in the code, the actual generated values are completely driven by the implementation of `generate`, but they will relate to the respective generator/process in another program.

Comment: @Ancoron but if you I run your code, I can't see any "A"s or "B"s in my output!

Comment: Of course not! ;-) Examples, `Xn`'s are just examples to show the expected ordered round-robin output.

Comment: Well a big reason why it's "so slow" is the `Queue`. Try to use it as less as you can because than multiprocessing is going to be fast! It's like you would have 4 workers and each of them has to paint 1 wall which have the same size but they have only one paint pot... and in this case the paint pot is your Queue! They all depend on the bucket and can't work if another worker uses it.

Comment: I know that the Queue is the problematic point. I am currently thinking about an `mp.Array` for each producer as a buffer to fill and then notify the consumer to write them out as soon as all buffers are filled. Double- or triple-buffering comes to mind here to avoid idle-times. I simply cannot generate all values and then print them in the order I need because it would be too much for the RAM (final generated values will not be that short or just too many).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with a lot of different options, the (currently final) solution for me will be using a [Memory mapped file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) and without output to stdout.

After implementing also a change to more closely resemble one of the generator output types (UUID's - 36 characters + new line - 16-bytes value from generator), the resulting numbers at my machine are:

#### single-threaded

```
$ time python3 threading_output.py --threads 1 --count 10000000 | wc -l
10000000

real    0m15.915s
user    0m16.045s
sys     0m0.629s
```

#### Multiprocessing with cinda BytesQueue

```
$ time python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000 | wc -l
10000000

real    0m30.005s
user    0m53.543s
sys     0m28.072s
```

#### Multiprocessing with mmap

```
$ time python3 threading_output.py --threads 4 --count 10000000 --output-file test.txt

real    0m6.637s
user    0m18.688s
sys     0m1.265s
```

This looks much better with a speed-up factor of ~2.4. Although we are using more memory here, the system should allow

#### Details

The actual code for the mmap version is making use of the slice notation write access of memory mapped files so that each process can write to its own "slots". To avoid too much memory being used, each process also maps only a specific region of the output file (`mmap.PAGESIZE * <bytes_per_entry> * 100 * <processes>`) and re-maps the next region after `mmap.PAGESIZE * 100` entries per process.

#### Complete Test Code

The `mmap` version is implemented with functions `mmapped` and `produce_mm`:

```py
import random
import argparse
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
from cinda.ipc.queue import BytesQueue as Queue
from cinda.ipc import free
import mmap
import os


class DataGenerator:
    _id = 0

    def __init__(self, id: int, **kwargs):
        self._id = id

    def generate(self):
        return self._id.to_bytes(8, 'big') + random.getrandbits(64).to_bytes(8, 'big')


def produce(generator, q, num: int):
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        i += 1
        q.put(generator.generate())


def consume(queues: list, num: int):
    i = 0
    q_count = len(queues)

    while i < num:
        # enforce round-robin printing...
        q = queues[i % q_count]

        i += 1
        hex = q.get().hex()
        sys.stdout.write('%8s-%4s-%4s-%4s-%12s\n' % (hex[:8], hex[8:12], hex[12:16], hex[16:20], hex[20:]))


def multi_processed(num: int, processes: int):
    per_process = int(num / processes)
    if num % processes != 0:
        per_process += 1

    q = list()
    g = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        name = 'gen-%d' % i
        free(name)
        q.append(Queue(name, 10000, 16))
        g.append(DataGenerator(i + 1))

    procs = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=produce, args=(g[i], q[i], per_process))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    consume(q, num)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()


def produce_mm(generator, out_file, num: int, offset: int, num_total: int, processes: int):
    entry_size = 37 # number of bytes per entry
    seek_relative = processes * entry_size # relative offset to next slot
    seek_offset = offset * entry_size # initial slot offset for this process
    buffer_switch = mmap.PAGESIZE * 100 # number of "my" entries per buffer
    buffer_num = buffer_switch * processes # number of entries to mmap at any time
    buffer_size = buffer_num * entry_size # actual mmap'd buffer size
    buffer_offset = 0

    size = num_total * entry_size

    with open(out_file, "r+b") as f:
        mem = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), min(num_total * entry_size, buffer_size), access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)

        # generate and write the first entry (saves an if-clause later)
        hex = generator.generate().hex()
        mem[seek_offset:(seek_offset + entry_size)] = ('%8s-%4s-%4s-%4s-%12s\n' % (hex[:8], hex[8:12], hex[12:16], hex[16:20], hex[20:])).encode('US-ASCII')

        (i, j) = (1, 1)
        while i < num:
            # close current, create next buffer and reset entry offset
            if (i % buffer_switch) == 0:
                mem.flush()
                mem.close()
                buffer_offset += buffer_size
                buffer_size = min(size - buffer_offset, buffer_size)
                #sys.stderr.write('New buffer[%d] at %d\n' % (buffer_size, buffer_offset))
                mem = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), buffer_size, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE, offset=buffer_offset)
                j = 0

            # calculate [start:end] offsets for this slot
            off_start = seek_relative * j + seek_offset
            off_end = off_start + entry_size
            if off_end > buffer_size:
                break

            hex = generator.generate().hex()
            try:
                mem[off_start:off_end] = ('%8s-%4s-%4s-%4s-%12s\n' % (hex[:8], hex[8:12], hex[12:16], hex[16:20], hex[20:])).encode('US-ASCII')
            except IndexError as e:
                sys.stderr.write('%s (tried [%d:%d] for mmap size %d, offset %d)\n' % (e, off_start, off_end, buffer_size, j))
                break

            (i, j) = (i + 1, j + 1)


def mmapped(num: int, processes: int, out_file):
    per_process = int(num / processes)
    if num % processes != 0:
        per_process += 1

    with open(out_file, "wb") as f:
        f.seek((num * 37 - 1), os.SEEK_SET)
        f.write(b'\0')
        f.flush()

    g = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        g.append(DataGenerator(i + 1))

    procs = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=produce_mm, args=(g[i], out_file, per_process, i, num, processes))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()


def single_threaded(num: int, processes: int):
    g = list()
    for i in range(processes):
        g.append(DataGenerator(i + 1))

    for i in range(num):
        j = i % processes
        hex = g[j].generate().hex()
        sys.stdout.write('%8s-%4s-%4s-%4s-%12s\n' % (hex[:8], hex[8:12], hex[12:16], hex[16:20], hex[20:]))


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Threading test')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--count', '-c', dest='count', type=int, default=1000000,
        help='How many total iterations (default: 1000000)')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--threads', '-t', dest='threads', type=int, default=1,
        help='how many threads to use (default: 1 - single-threaded)')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output-file', '-o', dest='out_file', type=str,
        help='specify output file to write into')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.threads > 1:
        if args.out_file is None:
            multi_processed(args.count, abs(args.threads))
        else:
            mmapped(args.count, abs(args.threads), args.out_file)
    else:
        single_threaded(args.count, mp.cpu_count())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I came back so I could post [this](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/) article. I think it may answer some of why there were such a speed deficit initially. Nice to see you found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I did a bit of testing and now I'm baffled. I did both multithreaded and asynchronous solutions and neither worked particularly well. I also copy and pasted your code, and it always hung, even when it was 'done'.

Just to note, in my code I used the number that it was given as the TID, instead of 4 random hex numbers because I wanted to make sure it was doing what you wanted. It was harder to tell with the other way, and it can be easily changed to hex.

Single Threaded:

```
import random
import sys

def generate():
    return random.randrange(-10, 10)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("NEED ARGS")
    exit(0)

num = int(sys.argv[1])
for x in range(num):
    for _ in range(x):
        print("[{}]: {}".format(x, generate()))
```

Multithreaded:

```
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from pebble import ThreadPool, ProcessExpired
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys 

def generate():
    return random.randrange(-10, 10) 

def produce(num):
    #tid = '%04x' % random.getrandbits(16)
    tid = num 
    i = 0 
    while i < num:
        print('[%s] %3d' % (tid, generate()))
        i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("NEED ARGS")
        exit(0)

    num = int(sys.argv[1])
    with ThreadPool(max_workers=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        future = pool.map(produce, range(num), timeout=3)
        iterator = future.result()
        while True:
            try:
                result = next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            except TimeoutError as error:
                print(error)
                break
            except ProcessExpired as error:
                print(error)
                break
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)
                break
```

To be honest, I didn't see a big change in speed. The multiprocessed one was actually slower, and this is about as basic as it can get. Something that I just remembered about is [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), which is known for its speed on computations. I really don't feel like setting it up, but I think it could be your solution given the simple, repetitive, and purely computational nature of your problem.

Benchmarks were:

.3 seconds for 100 iterations

10 seconds for single and 11 seconds for multi for 1000 iterations

I gave up over that because of how long it was taking. I don't know how to describe it, but you're doing 100 times more work every magnitude increase. Proof using Gauss' pattern thing:

You're doing the sum of every number up to num, which means 1 + 2 + ... and Gauss' pattern covers this. This should give a loose idea of just how big it is:

10 as an input takes 550 iterations

100 as an input takes 5050 iterations

1000 as an input takes 500500 iterations

10000 as an input takes 50005000 iterations

After throwing the data through excel it's O(n^2), which isn't too bad I guess. The equation is ~.55x^2 if you're curious.

[image: Gauss' graph]

Would you mind linking the other program variations you made so I can benchmark them against my own? Because honestly I would be curious to see if they're working correctly/am I doing something massively wrong.

**Tl;DR:  What tests/code are you using so I can compare? Have you tried PyPy? Would a database be okay as opposed to printing the numbers (it'd almost certainly be faster)? How did you manage to get your program to run so fast singlethreaded?**

Hope this helps!

EDIT:  Just to check, you do want to do the following, right? On the first iteration you print the ID and a random number ONCE. On the second iteration your print the ID and a random number TWICE. Just want to check.

EDIT 2:  The code should be fixed.

```
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from pebble import ThreadPool, ProcessExpired
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys

def generate():
    return random.randrange(-10, 10)

def produce(num):
    tid = '%04x' % random.getrandbits(16)
    for _ in range(num):
        print('[%s] %3d' % (tid, generate()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("NEED ARGS")
        exit(0)

    num = int(sys.argv[1])
    workers = int(sys.argv[2])
    num_per_worker = int(num/workers)

    #The magic numbers here are just optimizations. Feel free to change them
    with ThreadPool(max_workers=workers, max_tasks=50) as pool:
        future = pool.map(produce, (num_per_worker for _ in range(workers)),
                          chunksize=round(num/1024))
        iterator = future.result()
        while True:
            try:
                result = next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                break
```

EDIT 3:  Round Robin

```
from pebble import ThreadPool, ProcessExpired
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys 
from functools import partial

def generate():
    return random.randrange(-10, 10) 

def produce(num, magic_array):
    tid = '%04x' % random.getrandbits(16)
    for _ in range(num):
        magic_array.append('[%s] %3d' % (tid, generate()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("NEED ARGS")
        exit(0)

    num = int(sys.argv[1])
    workers = int(sys.argv[2])
    num_per_worker = int(num/workers)
    magic_array = []

    #This is the how the magic array is used as an argument.
    #There's probably a better way to do it, but I don't know it
    part_produce = partial(produce, magic_array=magic_array)
    #The magic numbers here are just optimizations. Feel free to change them
    with ThreadPool(max_workers=workers, max_tasks=50) as pool:
        future = pool.map(part_produce, (num_per_worker for _ in range(workers)), chunksize=num_per_worker)
        iterator = future.result()
        while True:
            try:
                result = next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                break

    #This is the important part. For every iteration/worker unit, it will go
    #through the list in steps of iteration/worker units, with a start offset
    #of x
    #Just printing takes about 5 seconds, but I don't think there's a faster
    #method because printing takes a long time anyway
    for x in range(num_per_worker):
        for y in magic_array[x::num_per_worker]:
            print(y)
```

Comment: "Just to check": no. As I tried to describe in the beginning and with my test code (which is the reason for `per_process = int(num / processes)`), I need to generate `num` output rows using `processes` generators, finally each having it's own configuration (which I disregarded for testing by simply using a random `generate`). The biggest problem actually is the output that needs to be iterate over the generators in-order. I'll update the code with the complete testing program I am using.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your code but I get the same hex value for every output if I use single threaded. Multithreaded doesn't have that same problem (when I use more than one thread as an argument)

Comment: Yes, that's intended for testing. There is one generator per process/thread. Of course, a solution that breaks up this correlation is also highly appreciated. :-)

Comment: New code is up. I'm on a laptop so I have no idea how well the above code should run on your PC, but I *think* it's what you want. If you want a different generator, all you have to do is replace the generator under the future variable, with whatever generator you'd like to use. If you give me an example I can try and do it for you. My benchmarks are pretty bad, but they're about ~35 seconds as opposed to the more than a minute you have.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating, and on my machine it gave me ~16.5 seconds for 10m values and is basically the same I had using no output ordering at all. But especially the round-robin ordered (over any number of generators) output of the values are a major functional criteria here.

Comment: So is there anything I should try and add? And i'm still confused what you mean by 'round robin'. You mean every thread goes once before going to the next iteration? That might be somewhat hard to implement, but I can try do it.

Comment: In my test program I implemented `generator` == `process`, because that is much easier to handle. But essentially, the order of the output values must iterate through the generator output values, so when generator `A` produces `1`,`2`,`3` and generator `B` produces `7`,`8`,`9` the output must be: `1`,`7`,`2`,`8`,`3`,`9`. No matter how fast each single generator produces its values. I've also updated the my test script code to include multiple generators for single-threaded execution.

Comment: @Ancoron okay, so I have round robin. The only stipulation is that it has the number of iterations has to be divisible by the number of workers/cpus. It also seems fairly fast on my computer, but I can try and mess with it on my computer if it's not fast enough.

Comment: Erhm, OK. The third iteration now is effectively single-threaded and stores all values in memory before printing them out. single-threaded execution itself is faster here and holding everything in memory is not an option either. Sorry. I think there is a fundamental performance bottleneck in Python IPC.